# Change the data in div periodically on django template

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, django

I want to change the comments (data) appearing on my page periodically. I have referred to a question here, yet the data is not changing, it does on page refresh though.

Here's my code in **views.py**

```
def index(request):
    count = Article.objects.all().count()
    comments = Article.objects.values_list('content')[randint(0, count - 1)][0]
    context = {
        'current_date': datetime.now(),
        'title': 'Home',
        'comments': comments,
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

And **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', index, name='index'),
    url(r'^about/$',about),
    # url(r'^comments/$',ArticleCreateView.as_view(), name='comments'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

And **index.html**

```
<div>
    <div id="comments">
        {{ comments }}
    </div> 
</div>

<script>
    var ALARM_URL = "{% url 'index' %}";
    function refresh() {
        $.ajax({
            url: ALARM_URL,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#comments').html(data);
            }
        });
    };
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        refresh();
        var int = setInterval("refresh()", 3000);
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: What does the `ALARM_URL` returns?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It points to the method where the code to be executed is located. I got that from the answers here, I'm new to using django and js, so don't know the concepts in depth yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view `index()` returns an `HTML` page, so the argument `data` contains a whole HTML page.

You probably want to add a second view that returns `JSON` data only, maybe like this:

**views.py**

```
def index_data(request):
    # here you return whatever data you need updated in your template
    return JsonResponse({
        'something_1': 0,
    })
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^data$', index_data, name='index-data'),
```

And then in your AJAX call you do something like this:

```
url: "{% url 'index-data' %}",
success: function(data) {
    $('#comments').html(data['something_1']);
}
```

Let us know if that helps.

---

EDIT

You probably also need to adjust your timer; pass it the function name, but without calling it and also not as a string (see [the docs of `setInterval`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)):

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    refresh();
    setInterval(refresh, 3000);
});
```

Comment: So I added a new view as you suggested. After doing that the comments which appeared on my index.html disappeared and are now visible on /data url which is not what I wanted to do. I want the comments to refresh in the div section on index.html page itself.

Comment: @Meg I edited my answer to include a comment about your timer. Maybe that helps?

Comment: I made the changes in the code yet the comments do not change as per the  timer. It changes only on page refresh!

Comment: @Meg what do you see in your browser console? Any errors or warning from javascript? If you add the line `console.log('test refresh');` in your `refresh()` method, does anything get printed to the browser console?

Comment: I did that. There was a syntax error with my js code. Thanks a lot for your help. The comments have started changing as per the timer.